# Excel - Why is this equality check failing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Excel to check imported bank statements. One of the tests I use is to make sure that the balance column equals the previous balance plus the row amount. In all circumstances so far it has worked, but with this specific set of values, it seems to fail:

[image: Equality check fails]

The cell contents are as follows:

```
A1: 11474.97
A2: -10781.34
A3: =A1+A2
A4: 693.63
A5: =A3=A4
```

I am using Office 16.0.6965.2117. Is this a bug, or am I missing something fundamental about how the equality operator works?

Comment: If I multiply cell A3 and A4 by seemingly any value and then do the equality check, it works.

Comment: It is better to use =If(A3=A4,"OK","Different")

Comment: That formula also comes up Different - the equality check fails

Comment: I do not see any reason for this to fail (which it also does on excel 2016 64bit), but comparing floating point numbers is a known challenge.

Comment: Format the numbers the same way (decimal places) it might be different even if you see it the same

Comment: Excel tends to round numbers, if A1 or A2 are not text inputs but formula inputs then A3 might be "693.630000001" which excel will see as different to "693.63"

Comment: Try to Round (=ROUND(A1+A2,2) it will be ok even =A3=A4

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose is correct. I just tried changing the number format with 30 decimal digits, and it shows 693.629999999999000000000000000000 in A3, while A4 shows 693.630000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose A1 and A2 are actually text inputs in this case, but the problem seems to be the formula in A3, as Darius noted. I would expect Excel to handle such simple floating point comparisons better, but I guess the solution is to round numbers before doing comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the starting numbers are a lot larger than the result, you’ll stumble upon precision loss due to [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) arithmetic. [Excel uses IEEE 754 Double Precision](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel).

I won’t delve into the details but instead illustrate the issue. First, let’s convert all the numbers to IEEE 754:

```
  11474.97 ≙ 01000000 11000110 01101001 01111100 00101000 11110101 11000010 10001111
```

... where *0* is the sign (positive), **10000001100** is the exponent and the rest is the mantissa.

```
 -10781.34 ≙ 11000000 11000101 00001110 10101011 10000101 00011110 10111000 01010010
```

```
    693.63 ≙ 01000000 10000101 10101101 00001010 00111101 01110000 10100011 11010111
```

As you can see, the large numbers happen to have the same exponent. The larger the exponent, the less precise the stored number is:

```
  11474.97 →  11474.9699999999993451638147235
```

```
 -10781.34 → -10781.3400000000001455191522837
```

```
    693.63 →    693.629999999999995452526491135
```

As you can already see from the aligned numbers, the way 693.63 is stored is more precise.

So, the result of adding the numbers is:

```
01000000 10000101 10101101 00001010 00111101 01110000 10100011 11010000
```

Let’s compare again:

```
01000000 10000101 10101101 00001010 00111101 01110000 10100011 11010000 – Result
01000000 10000101 10101101 00001010 00111101 01110000 10100011 11010111 – Constant
```

So, not quite the same. You should always compare floating point numbers with a tolerance. Like this:

```
abs(a - b) < 0.000000001
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the technical detail. Accepting this answer because it's so comprehensive, and I think the tolerance approach to equality comparisons is probably more correct than simply rounding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's doing it but I'm using Office 2010 and getting the same issue.

To get around it, I changed A5 to read =ROUND(A3, 2)=ROUND(A4, 2) which fixed the problem so I can only assume there's some sort of minor issue with fractions of mini amounts somewhere causing the error.

And, as @yass said in the comments, using an IF statement would work better and keep things a bit neater for you though in this instance, it's not 100% essential.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I am actually using it for conditional formatting, so in that case the IF statement is unnecessary.